# Can't fetch or push anything to GitHub via GitHub Desktop

Tags: macos, github, fetch, github-desktop, .netrc

[.netrc parser error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEFZB.png)

Suddenly today, i can't fetch or push anything to GitHub via GitHub Desktop. how can i solve this problem?

I tried this commands, but nothing is changed.

$ git config --global --unset credential.helper
$ git config --global credential.helper cache

Comment: Can you please provide screenshot of error message?

Comment: Can you look at the `~/.netrc` file?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEFZB.png this is the screenshot of error message. @AshishBhanderi . I looked that file but it has another applications data in it . I solve the problem by the way, just restart the pc and magic happens.